# modifiy data of json file

Tags: python, json, json-value

How can I modify the values of json file using python?
so my json file is:

```json
{
  "roll no": "210",
  "school": "DAP",
  "city": "Delhi",
  "hobbies": [
    {
      "dance": "yes"
    },
 {
      "singing": "yes"
    },
 {
      "travel": "yes"
    },
            ]
}
```

so this is my `json` and I want to replace the values like:
roll no= 211 and travel="no" ,singing="no"

I have tried:

```py
with open("student.json","r") as file:
    data=json.load(file)
    data["roll no"]= "211"
    
    for x in data:
        x["hobbies"]["singing"]="no"
        x["hobbies"]["travel"]="no"

            
        with open("student.json","w") as file:

        json.dump(data,file,indent=4)
```

I have tried this but the only change I'm able to doing is roll no,but I'm unable to change the hobbies values
expected output:

```json
{
  "roll no": "211",
  "school": "DAP",
  "city": "Delhi",
  "hobbies": [
    {
      "dance": "yes"
    },
 {
      "singing": "no"
    },
 {
      "travel": "no"
    },
            ]
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you're not getting `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` error, when accessing a list item ,  You should update you'r code to       `data["hobbies"][0]["travel"] = "no"` you should access the index of the list before the accessing the dic in it. And also for loop is not required if you're only update 2 item in the list.

Comment: your line `with open("student.json","w") as file:`  doesn;t have any code inside. you need to put some code there

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: Maybe it does, maybe its just that the `with open(...` is indented too much.

Comment: do you also want to replace "dance"? So set every hobby to no?

Comment: im getting error "string indices must be integers" please help

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: no i just wanted to change travel and singing with valu no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i have updated hobbies for new roll number

```
import json

json_data = '''{
  "roll no": "210",
  "school": "DAP",
  "city": "Delhi",
  "hobbies": [
    {
      "dance": "yes"
    },
 {
      "singing": "yes"
    },
 {
      "travel": "yes"
    }
            ]
}
'''

data = json.loads(json_data)

data["roll no"] = "211"
for hobby in data["hobbies"]:
    for upd_hobby in ["singing", "travel"]:
        if upd_hobby in hobby:
            hobby[upd_hobby] = "no"

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "roll no": "211",
    "school": "DAP",
    "city": "Delhi",
    "hobbies": [
        {
            "dance": "yes"
        },
        {
            "singing": "no"
        },
        {
            "travel": "no"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As i said in above comment, you will get an error while passing index as string to list.

See below code

```
with open("./students.json", "r") as file:
  data = json.load(file)
```

Methode 1 (If the hobbies are hardcoded)

```
data["roll no"] = "211"
data["hobbies"][1]["singing"] = "no"
data["hobbies"][2]["travel"] = "no"
```

Method 2 (if you want to dynamically include some hobbies to change  their state 'yes' - 'no')

```
hobbies_inc = ["singing", "travel"] # Create a list hobbies, that need to be included

for x in data["hobbies"]:
   if list(x)[0] in hobbies_inc:
        x[list(x)[0]] = "no"
```

Answer (score 0):

'hobbies' is a list of dict so you should write:

```
with open("student.json", "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

data["roll no"] = "211"
data["hobbies"][1]["singing"] = "no"
data["hobbies"][2]["travel"] = "no"

        
with open("student.json","w") as file:
    json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
```

Comment: Ok, this looks good. Have you tried it?

Comment: dance is also getting changes as "no"

Comment: i just want to change travel and singing with value no

Comment: Now I tested it and it works